# 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' object is not iterable

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

Recently, I started programming in python, right now I'm writing a GUI for a password and pseudo-random number generator. I had this problem:
TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' object is not iterable

```
    btn_2 = QPushButton("Generate password", self)
    btn_2.resize(100,30)
    btn_2.move(340, 250)
    btn_2.resize(100, 30)
    btn_2.clicked.connect(self.btn1)

    btn_3 = QPushButton("Generate pseudorandom numbers", self)
    btn_3.move(140, 250)
    btn_3.resize(180, 30)
    btn_3.clicked.connect(self.btn2)

    self.line = QLineEdit(self)
    self.line.setPlaceholderText("Enter the expected string length")
    self.line.resize(250, 20)
    self.line.move(200, 220)
    self.onlyInt = QIntValidator()
    self.line.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
    self.show()

def btn1(self):
    mark = self.line
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    print("".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in mark))
def btn2(self):
    mark = self.line
    chars = string.digits
    print("".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in mark))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `self.line.text` rather than `self.line`.

So:

```py
mark = int(self.line.text)
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
print("".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(mark))
```

Note that I've also replaced `mark` with `range(mark)` which is probably what you want here.

In general when given an XYZ isn't iterable error, go and look at the docs for XYZ and see how to get at whatever it is storing and you want to iterate over.  In this case we see that we can [get at the text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) which is presumably what you want with `.text`.  But as it happens I think you want to iterate `self.line.text` *times* (hence your checking for an int), so we cast to int and then iterate through `range(int(self.line.text))`.

Comment: Note that, unless the `true_property` is explicitly set in PySide6 (which I don't suggest), properties are accessible with parentheses like standard Qt and PyQt: `self.line.text()`